# Stop Opening the Print Dialog

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm trying to printing the barcode through JavaScript.

What I did is : print the barcode inside a div and I print the HTML content through JavaScript.

### The code I wrote is as follow:

```
function printBarCode(divToPrint,ProductName,NameOfPrinter) {
    var newWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0');
    var htmlStart = '<div align="center"><p>'+ProductName+'</p>';
    var htmlEnd = '<p>'+NameOfPrinter+'</p></div>';

    var passToPrinter = htmlStart + divToPrint.html() + htmlEnd;
    newWin.document.write(passToPrinter);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

My problem is , How am I stop opening the print Dialog on the browser, Can't I print it without opening the print dialog on browser ?

Thanks in advance for the kind help.

Comment: No, you can't print without print dialog.

Comment: Is there any other way to print directly without using the dialog

Comment: "_No, you can't print without print dialog_"

Comment: yes you cant do because you  javascript needs a initial printing platform ...if you dont want in browser then you have to access your dekstop application like Word , Paint Excel etc which will open print there .

Comment: If you could, that would be a security issue, because you could print anything to any user, without their approval. Also, that would require the JS to have access to the connected printers, which is bad.

Comment: Some settings can be found on different browsers, if you need this for your own purposes only, you could check e.g. [this old about:config setting](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=48336) if you're on FF, though I'm not sure if that particular setting exists anymore.